# Update list dynamically between two different users

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, dynamic

I am using Rails 4, JQuery, Postgres.

I would like to have a scenario where User_1 has a form and a list and User_2 has the same list.  As User_1 adds to their list, I would like it to update the list for User_2.  It doesn't have to be by keystroke and can include a submit action from User_1 but I would like to use AJAX as to not need any page reloads.

I can update the list dynamically for User_1 using a remote true form and but how do I get the update to take place for User_2?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have 2 ways:

1. Via "Polling": every X seconds you fetch list items via AJAX so you can update the list in user_2's page

   Pro: it's simple

   Con: it's resource-intensive (requests arrives even if user_1 has NOT added anything to his list)
2. You establish a persistent connection with the server so server pushes new items directly into user_2's list.

   Pro: it's clean

   Con: it's more complicated